# Erroneous SUM when using JOIN on SQL request

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi i have two tables with a lot of data. I have to get some data of both tables. to do this i use an `inner join`. But when i use `SUM` i get wrong result. i know that the result is multiplied as many rows returned. How can i get arround this ?

The request :

```
select  SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie != 18 AND det.IdGarantie != 17 AND det.IdGarantie!= 11 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS 'cot nette',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 18 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fond comp',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 11 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS 'Carte Verte',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 17 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS 'Adhesion',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie != 18 AND det.IdGarantie != 17 AND det.IdGarantie!= 11 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS 'Taxe',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 18 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS 'Taxe Fond Comp',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 17 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS 'Taxe Adhésion',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 11 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS 'Taxe carte verte',
    SUM(hst.Q_Access) as 'Access'
from  OtoHistorique hst
inner Join OtoHistoriqueDet det On det.IdHistorique = hst.IdHistorique
where hst.POLICE = 3221086
```

i get 60 in **Access** column when the expected result is 20

Anyone can help me with this ? Sorry if i use bad syntax in my request but i'm just a beginner in SQL and for the moment the result is more important than the syntax.

Comment: Your SQL is incomplete (see last line of your code). Please update to have the full, original defintion

Comment: I update the request with the `Where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have one-to-many relationship between the tables, which means some of the values for `SUM` get duplicated.
You can go around this by avoiding the join like this:

```
select  SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie != 18 AND det.IdGarantie != 17 AND det.IdGarantie!= 11 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS 'cot nette',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 18 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fond comp',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 11 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS 'Carte Verte',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 17 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS 'Adhesion',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie != 18 AND det.IdGarantie != 17 AND det.IdGarantie!= 11 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS 'Taxe',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 18 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS 'Taxe Fond Comp',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 17 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS 'Taxe Adhésion',
    SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 11 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS 'Taxe carte verte',
    (SELECT SUM(hst.Q_Access) 
     FROM OtoHistorique hst 
     WHERE det.IdHistorique = hst.IdHistorique) as 'Access' 
FROM OtoHistoriqueDet det 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM OtoHistorique hst2 
              WHERE hst2.POLICE = 3221086 
                AND hst2.IdHistorique = det.IdHistorique)
```

This could probably be more optimized but we'd need more info on the logic between the two tables.

Comment: unfortunatly i can't give you the model beacause the tables has more than 20 columns. When i try your suggestion i get: `Column 'OtoHistoriqueDet.IdHistorique' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY claus`

Comment: I did some change to your solution and it works fine. i replace the `WHERE`condition by the appropriate one. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to do the aggregation before the join:

```
select det.*,
       SUM(hst.Q_Access) as "Access"
from  OtoHistorique hst inner Join
      (select det.IdHistoric,
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie != 18 AND det.IdGarantie != 17 AND det.IdGarantie!= 11 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) as "cot nette"
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 18 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS "Fond comp",
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 11 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS "Carte Verte",
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 17 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS "Adhesion",
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie != 18 AND det.IdGarantie != 17 AND det.IdGarantie!= 11 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS "Taxe",
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 18 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS "Taxe Fond Comp",
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 17 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS "Taxe Adhésion",
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 11 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS "Taxe carte verte",
              SUM(hst.Q_Access) as "Access"
       from OtoHistoriqueDet det
       group by det.IdHistorique
      ) det
      On det.IdHistorique = hst.IdHistorique
where hst.POLICE = 3221086;
```

Because you are filtering the query, this might be expensive.  The entire details table has to be aggregated.  So, you can do the join in the subquery for filtering purposes and then again for the calculation:

```
select det.*,
       SUM(hst.Q_Access) as "Access"
from  OtoHistorique hst inner Join
      (select det.IdHistoric,
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie != 18 AND det.IdGarantie != 17 AND det.IdGarantie!= 11 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) as "cot nette"
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 18 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS "Fond comp",
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 11 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS "Carte Verte",
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 17 THEN det.Q_PrimeNette ELSE 0 END) AS "Adhesion",
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie != 18 AND det.IdGarantie != 17 AND det.IdGarantie!= 11 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS "Taxe",
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 18 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS "Taxe Fond Comp",
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 17 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS "Taxe Adhésion",
              SUM(CASE WHEN det.IdGarantie = 11 THEN det.Q_Taxe ELSE 0 END) AS "Taxe carte verte"
       from OtoHistoriqueDet det join
            OtoHistorique hst 
            On det.IdHistorique = hst.IdHistorique and hst.POLICE = 3221086
       group by det.IdHistorique
      ) det
      On det.IdHistorique = hst.IdHistorique
where hst.POLICE = 3221086;
```

Comment: Thank youfor your quick answer, i tried your solution but i get a lot of errors. it seems like he doesn't recognize the `det` alias. can you please comment your second request. if i understand you calculate all the data in the subquery?

Comment: @113408 . . . It is not obvious to me why the `det` alias would not be understood.  As for the second question, it is calculating all the fields from the `det` table (I had accidentally left in the `"Access"` calculation).